# Prevent bluetooth speaker from shutting off when there is no audio?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, speakers, bluetooth-speaker

If I'm playing audio my bluetooth speaker stays on, however if there is no audio it eventually shuts off, how can I prevent it from shutting off?

The reason is that I want it to play an alarm in the morning but if it just turns itself off before the alarm it's no good.

*The bluetooth speaker is connected to power, so that's not the issue.*

In case this is device specific: **JBL Flip 6**

Comment: One solution: Just play an audio file on low volume, e.g. the white noise audio file from [Blanket](https://github.com/rafaelmardojai/blanket): https://github.com/rafaelmardojai/blanket/tree/master/data/resources/sounds